# jQuery validate + ajaxSubmit on multiple forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate multiple forms in one single page with the jQuery validation plugin but it validates only the first form in the page.

Here is my code:

```
$('form.reply_form').validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit(optionsReplies);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Is for a list of reply forms in the page (image facebook). If I try to use the third form, for example, it validates the first one and if the first one is blank it wont submit.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the particular plugin you are using, but it sounds like it only uses the first element returned.
An `each()` method may help:

```
$('form.reply_form').each(function(){
    $(this).validate({
        ...
    });
});
```